# AWS SageMaker Validation Error when calling the CreateTrainingJob operation: Input Hyper parameter includes AWS access keys or tokens

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sagemaker

When creating a sagemaker training job using the `sagemaker` python package (using SKLearn or Tensorflow estimators), I pass in a number of hyperparameters.  I create a single training job for each of our clients (we have 200), and the job gets named `TrainModel-[client_id]-[int:1-50]-[uuid]` (unsure if this is important, will explain why soon).  The hyperparameters are all integers or strings, and none resemble an AWS access key or token. For 199 out of 200 clients, the training job is created and runs flawlessly.

For one, however, I get the following error: `(ValidationException) when calling the CreateTrainingJob operation: Input Hyper parameter contains AWS access key id or access token`.  This validation is warned about in the [documentation](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/training/estimators.html#sagemaker.estimator.EstimatorBase), and I have ensured that I do not include any AWS access key ids or tokens (otherwise how would the other 199 run without incident?).

I have examined the actual hyperparameters as they are recorded in the Estimator, and nothing is out of the ordinary.  The only hyperparameters that change per client on a given day are the client name, client id, and the integer ranging 1-50 (which indicates a sub-division of the client).

I have read through the source code and cannot find the actual code that validates whether AWS access key ids and tokens exist in the inputs, and the Error and Traceback are utterly uninformative (I can't tell which parameter is the offender).  Based on the qualities of the hyper parameters that change, the only culprit could possibly be the client name, which does not include anything to do with AWS keys or tokens.  Is it possible that, for whatever reason, the validation function (I assume it's a regular expression) incorrectly identifies this particular client name, which again, has zero reference to anything in our AWS or in generic AWS terms, as an AWS key or token?

Has anyone encountered this before?  If so what was your solution?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that, whatever the way AWS checks for access tokens and key IDs, it is not very accurate.  It was detecting the `client_name` as an access token or key ID, which is was certainly not.  Removing this parameter solved the issue.  Watch out for random strings being miscategorized in this way.